# d3 xhr adding loading cursor

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, d3.js

I am trying to make a xmlhttprequest from

```
d3.xhr("Data-mapper?Function-name=tree-data", "application/json", function (i,d){
    console.log(d);
    return d;
});
```

I am able to get the response data as well but i want to know if i can add a loading cursor when the call is made.. Or progress bar ...

One more thing i wanted to ask is how can we send data when we make a call to get data from server side i.e

> `d3.json(...) or d3.xhr(...)`

Comment: acutally wanted to ask one more question  when i making call `d3.xhr("DataMapper?function-name=PieChart","application/json",
     function(i,d){
      jsondata=JSON.parse(d.response);
      console.log("inside "+jsondata);
      return d.response;
      }); console.log("jsondata "+jsondata);` I have now kept this inside the html script .The issue is  i am able to get data inside the function but when i try outside the function i dont get the data .But if the same code i paste it in console of chrome i am able to see both the data . why is this so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<pre id='pre'>loading...</pre>
```

**JS**

```
d3.json("http://filltext.com/?rows=5&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&delay=10", function (err, data){
    var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(d, null, 4);
    console.log(data);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/BnaLu/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "loading" screen by adding it in the beginning and removing in the callback:

```
addLoadingScreen();
d3.json(..., function(error, data) {
  // do something
  removeLoadingScreen();
});
```

I have used this technique [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/mpte/).

To answer your second question, you can pass parameters as GET parameters:

```
d3.json("http://www.foo.com/script?parameterA=foo&parameterB=bar", function(error, data) {
});
```