# d3.xhr example or AJAX d3's way

Tags: ajax, d3.js

I've been looking for an example of updating data with d3.xhr but have not seen anything obvious, or at least of my level of understanding. The following 2 links are close but no cigar:

1. [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819652/d3-xhr-adding-loading-cursor)
2. [from mbostock’s block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941)

I look around more and found this example in jquery and php. I tried it and understand the code. I would appreciate if you give me an equivalent code in d3.xhr or d3.json. BTW, what is different between d3.xhr and d3.json, and when to use what? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// AJAX & PHP example
// http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/learning-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-php-video-tutorial/
    if ($_GET['ip']) {
        $ip = gethostbyname($_GET['ip']);
        echo($ip);
        exit;
   }  
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Get Reverse IP</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Please enter a domain name
        <input type="text" id="searchip">
        <div id="resultip"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#searchip').change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: 'ip=' + $('#searchip').val(),
                        success: function(msg){
                            $('#resultip').html(msg);
                        }
                    }); // Ajax Call
                }); //event handler
            }); //document.ready
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you read the d3 xhr/json docs? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

Comment: I did, I still don't get it. Can you give more hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In fact it has less coding, :) I sincerely hope that the answer would be useful to someone.

```
<?php
// AJAX & PHP example
    if ($_GET['ip']) {
        $ip = gethostbyname($_GET['ip']);
        echo($ip);
        exit;
   }  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Get Reverse IP</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Please enter a domain name
        <input type="text" id="searchip">
        <div id="resultip"></div>
        <script>
            d3.select('#searchip').on("change", function() {
                d3.xhr('xhr.php?ip='+this.value, function(data) {
                    d3.select('#resultip').html(data.response);
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. d3's helpers make life very easy.